# How can I write this as a loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dataframe

I Have a DataFrame (5910x65) with columns from X1 to X64 and at least Y.
Now I want for to calculate the outlier with the .25quantil and .75quantil, but i don't want to write the code for every column (X1 to X64).

Aspacialy I don't know how to write 
    describe=df.X1.describe()
that a loop would replace 'X1' in the next turn with 'X2' and so on
I tried 'X'+str(i+1) for i in range(len(df.columns)-1), but I can't navigate with the result in df.?.describe()

```
describe=df.X1.describe()
col=df.X1
faktor=10
qabs=abs(describe[6]-describe[4])
q1=describe[4]-qabs*faktor
q3=describe[6]+qabs*faktor
under=col[(col)<q1]
above=col[(col)>q3]
print(col[(col)<q1])
print(col[(col)>q3])
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the access of the column from `.` to a key-style lookup like `df['col']`:

```py
for i in range(1, 65): # will end at 64
    describe=df[f'X{i}'].describe()
    col=df[f'X{i}']
    faktor=10
    qabs=abs(describe[6]-describe[4])
    q1=describe[4]-qabs*faktor
    q3=describe[6]+qabs*faktor
    under=col[(col)<q1]
    above=col[(col)>q3]
    print(col[(col)<q1])
    print(col[(col)>q3])
```